# .htaccess remove file extension with exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to remove all the file extensions (like `.php`) from my URL/website and redirect to the pages without the extensions. I came up with this solution so far (in `.htaccess`):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

This works fine so far.

But I need an exception rule for one site. This site should keep his file extension or else I can't send data via the POST method. The solution most users offer is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^todo\.php$ - [L]
```

But this solution doesn't work for me for whatever reason. Does anyone else has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Try this